# Are there material components that could be harvested from monsters?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, spell-components

Back in the Forgotten Realms novels based on *Advanced Dungeons & Dragons*, there was a female wizard character introduced after having killed a monster (I believe an owlbear) and having harvested its fur and feathers for material components that she could resell, with the idea being that materials harvested from monsters would be more powerful than a more common source.

I remember, at the time, being very excited by the concept but quite disappointed when, after reading through all of the spells in the *Player's Manual*, there seemed to be no spells that would potentially use owlbear feathers (although the Lightning Bolt did involve fur and amber), and for that matter, there were very few components that looked like one could replace them with monster materials.

Leaving aside the lack of actual mechanics for monster matter components, are there any spells in current 5e D&D that use material components that one might substitute with bits and body parts harvested from a monster?

Comment: Is this 'list almost every component of every spell'? That's a big and ever expanding list so I have voted to close this as too broad.

Comment: I think this is a potentially interesting question, but I also recognize that the scope of material components has shifted since the time when I first wondered this. I am content for it to be closed.

Answer (score -1):

You've asked:

> are there any spells in current 5e D&D that use material components that might be able to be substituted with an item from a monster?

The answer is:

### Yes, about half the spells with material components

A good way to search for these is to use a view such as https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells and use Advanced Search to scan for spells with the "M" material component.

Scanning through the spells, I found:

- the *minor illusion* cantrip uses "a bit of fleece". Maybe the bit of fleece could be from a monster?
- the *acid stream* spell from UA uses "a bit of rotten food".  Maybe the bit of rotten food is a piece of a monster?
- the *chromatic orb* spell uses "a diamond worth 50gp".  Maybe the diamond can be replaced with something from a monster?
- the *grease* spell uses "a bit of pork rind or butter".  Maybe you can replace that with something from a monster?

The problem is that, for basically any spell with a material component, you can append "maybe you can replace this with something from a monster?" to it and get a valid answer to this question.

(Some spells use obviously manmade material components, such as *message* which uses "a short piece of copper wire".  You can still consider the possibility of substituting a monster part for the copper wire, but it's more of a stretch.)

I think a better way to think about this would be: "given that I killed this monster and harvested some of its parts, what spell would benefit from using these parts as material components?"

So, for example, a fire-aligned monster might boost a fire spell (or a fire protection spell).  A displacer beast might boost the *blur* spell.  Et cetera.  But even this is all very homebrewy, and probably would not make a good question.

---

An exception to all this homebrew is harvesting dragons.  The Dragon Scale Mail is a Very Rare magic item which is explicitly made from the scales of a dragon.  Searching the magic items list may give you other examples of magic items which are made from monster parts, although, again, this would be a long search process and probably wouldn't make for a great question.

Comment: You said yes, then the explanation was maybe. This is good advice I think, but not sure it is an answer, at least not to the question as it stands.

Comment: The site you originally linked to in your answer rehosts non-SRD content for free, so I've replaced that link with a link to D&D Beyond instead (feel free to substitute any other site that doesn't rehost non-SRD content for free). See this relevant meta (and other linked metas): [Links to "D&D Tools" / dndtools and similar sites](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2770/33569)

Comment: I edited the body of the question, so you might want to update your quote.